# Storage prior to house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is it safe to store my weapons in the chest at High Hrothgar? Not for too long, though. Just long enough to sell off my Dragon Bones and Dragon Scales. I want to store my weapons there because with their weight added to the Bones and scales, I can't fast travel. And if you say a house is best, well, I'm selling the bones and scales so I can BUY a house later on. But please let me know of any safe places readily available until I can afford a house. Thank you.

Comment: Companions are the perfect storage! :P

Comment: @FEichinger until they die...